# In TensorFlow 2, are Datasets less efficient when doing image augmentation and combining numpy and ImageDataGenerator?

Tags: image-processing, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

`tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator` is super simple and easy to use to perform data augmentation. However, it seems to be much slower than using tf.data.Dataset to load data. I tried to load images tf.data.Dataset but couldn't figure out how to do the same data augmentation such as randomly shifting the width and height, randomly rotate, etc. I see in github that all these `tf.keras.image.ImageDataGenerator` augmentations seem to be using this function `tf.keras.preprocessing.image.apply_affine_transform`; however, the input must be numpy arrays.

For the best performance, do I have to rewrite the `tf.keras.preprocessing.image.apply_affine_transform` function so it takes TensorFlow tensors or can I just change the image to numpy during preprocessing phase in tf.data.Dataset, use the apply_affine_transform function for data augmentation, and cast it back to a Tensor?

Additionally, there is also tf.data.Dataset.from_generator() which looks like it can take an ImageDataGenerator.

Which is faster and more efficient for data loading: option 1, 2, or 3?

`import tensorflow as tf`

`AUTOTUNE = tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE`

`batch_size=32`

## option 1

`def preprocess(filename):
    tfImg = tf.io.read_file(file_path)
    numpyImg = tf.image.decode_jpeg(tfImg, channels=3).numpy()
    augNumpy = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.apply_affine_transform(numpyImg, change_some_arguments_here_for_augmentation)
    return tf.cast(augNumpy, tf.float32). # return augmented image as Tensor`

`list_ds = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(str(data_dir/'*/*'))`

`newAugmentedDataset = list_ds.map(preprocess, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE).shuffle(buffer_size=1000).repeat().batch_size(batch_size).prefetch(AUTOTUNE)`

## option 2

`def preprocess(filename):
    tfImg = tf.io.read_file(file_path)
    tfImg = tf.image.decode_jpeg(tfImg, channels=3)
    return rewritten_apply_affine_function(tfImg,...)`

`list_ds = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(str(data_dir/'*/*'))`

`newAugmentedDataset = list_ds.map(preprocess, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE).shuffle(buffer_size=1000).repeat().batch_size(batch_size).prefecth(AUTOTUNE)`

## option 3

`train_data_generator = ImageDataGenerator(augmentations_here)`

`ftrain_generator = train_data_generator.flow_from_directory(directory_here, shuffle=False)`

`ftrain_generator_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(lambda : ftrain_generator, 
    output_types=(tf.float32),
    output_shapes = (tf.TensorShape([None, height_here, width_here, num_channel]).prefetch(AUTOTUNE)`

## any of the options above goes into .fit

`model.fit(dataset_here, steps_per_epoch=sample_count/batch_size)`